# How load the related entities or relationshipentities using session.load in Java

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Using neo4j-ogm, I writed the followed code:
The Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages="com.neo4j.demo.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.neo4j.demo")
public class Neo4jApplication extends Neo4jConfiguration{
  @Bean
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
     return new SessionFactory("com.neo4j.demo.domain");
  }
  @Bean 
  public Neo4jServer neo4jServer(){
     return new        RemoteServer("http://username:password@localhost:7474","neo4j","neo4jhello");  
  }
  @Bean 
  @Scope(value="session",proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public Session getSession() throw Exception{
     return super.getSession();
  }
}
```

The NodeEntities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Message {
  @GraphId
   Long nodeId;
  @Index(unique=true)
   String id;
   Person author;
  @Relationship(type="LISTENER")
  List<Person>  listeners;
  //getters and setters  
} 
@NodeEntity
public class Person{
  @GraphId
  Long nodeId;
  @Index(unique=true)
  String id;
  String name;
  //getters and setters
}
```

When I use session.save to save the new instance of the Message, it works well. All of the related entities are saved. But the session.load seems work not well

```
List<Message> messages = session.loadAll(Message.class,N)
```

where the N is [-1,3], the results are same. The properties, such as author, listeners are null. Why?

Comment: The version of neo4j-ogm is 1.1.4

Comment: Hard to tell from the code shared. Can you share the debug log? Are you sure related entities were saved? BTW @Index is not supported in neo4j-ogm

Comment: When session.loadAll using,  the Message the neo4j log is:  
2016-02-09 23:12:48.918+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.i.q.QueryExecutionEngine]: MATCH (n:`Message`) WHERE n.`id` = { `id` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..2]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n)